# Finding the variance of a normally-distributed random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

X is a normally-distributed random variable, and 
$P[X<20] = 1/10 = P[X>100]$ 
I am trying to solve for the mean and the variance. 
 
I know that $\mu=60$ by symmetry. 
 
How can I solve for $\sigma^2$?

Comment: Something's off. The above suggests $P[20<X<100]=0$. That can't be right...

Comment: $$P(X<20)+P(20\leq X\leq100)+P(P>100)=1 \le P(20\le X\le 100)=0 $$ Why is $X$ normally distributed?

Comment: My apologies, the probability should be 1/10 rather than 1/2.

Comment: Hint: $0.1 = P\{X > 100\} = 1 - P\{X \leq 100\} = 1 - \Phi\left(\frac{100-60}{\sigma}\right)$. Do you have access to a table of values of $\Phi(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

The mean, as you say, must be 60.
So we know that the 90th percentile is 40 away from the mean.
With a standard normal, one with standard deviation 1, the 90th percentile is approximately 1.29 (you can find this in a table of standard normal percentiles).
So the standard deviation of your normal must be 40/1.29.  From which it follows
that the variance is the square, $[40/1.29]^2$